# Quill js editor backspace fails after inserting text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

I have a vue.js app where I set up a quill editor. There are placaceholder text buttons which whenever they get clicked they should paste the placeholder's content at the cursor. Which is kinda working however when I want to delete the text after inserting it I get two error messages (and one character from the text always remains which cannot be deleted):

```
quill.js:2999 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 4294967295 is larger than the node's length (1).
    at Selection.getBounds (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:2999:19)
    at Selection.scrollIntoView (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:3136:25)
    at Quill.scrollIntoView (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:1491:22)
    at Quill.focus (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:1236:12)
    at Keyboard.handleBackspace (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:4866:14)
    at eval (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:4614:34)
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:4591:34)
getBounds @ quill.js:2999
scrollIntoView @ quill.js:3136
scrollIntoView @ quill.js:1491
focus @ quill.js:1236
handleBackspace @ quill.js:4866
eval @ quill.js:4614
eval @ quill.js:4591


quill.js:3187 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 4294967294 is larger than the node's length (1).
    at Selection.setNativeRange (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:3187:17)
    at Selection.setRange (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:3211:29)
    at Quill.setSelection (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:1528:24)
    at Quill.modify (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:1663:10)
    at Quill.deleteText (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:1213:21)
    at Keyboard.handleBackspace (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:4862:14)
    at eval (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:4614:34)
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js?:4591:34)
```

But I'm unable to find the issue.

My code:

```js
import Quill from "quill";

let toolbarOptions = [
  ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
  [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }],
  [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
  [{ align: [] }],
  [{ color: [] }],
  ["clean"],
  [
    {
      keyboard: {
        bindings: {
          list: {
            key: "backspace",
            format: ["list"],
            handler: function (range, context) {
              if (range.index === 0) return;
              if (range.length === 0) {
                this.quill.deleteText(range.index - 1, 1, Quill.sources.USER);
              } else {
                this.quill.deleteText(range, Quill.sources.USER);
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
];

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editorOption: {
        modules: {
          toolbar: toolbarOptions,
        },
        theme: "snow",
        placeholder: "Please enter your text...",
      },
      editor: null,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    insertText(text) {
      let cursorIndex = this.editor.getSelection(true);

      this.editor.insertText(cursorIndex.index, text);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.editor = new Quill("#editor", this.editorOption);
  },
};
```

Comment: I have no idea what quill is, but can you try adding `console.log(range.index)` in your backspace handler function? That looks kind of like an overflow or something

Comment: @JoelPeltonen What is odd that the log does not show up at all. But without the handler function if I use backspace on an empty editor field it is overflowing - so I guess it is working (?). 
If I have already some text in the editor and I use the buttons to put some text at the cursor and backspace all the text the error does not show - only if I use the text insert buttons in the very beginning.

Comment: That is strange! Just to be sure, the log is the 1st thing in the function? 

Comment: @JoelPeltonen Yes. This all feels very odd.